# "Task: react-native-admob: compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED" is displayed by react-native-admob

Tags: android, react-native, admob

I implemented a video ad using react-native-admob.
When I built it this morning, the app that should have worked properly suddenly failed to build.

```
> Task :react-native-admob:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
22 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 20 up-to-date
/prj/node_modules/react-native-admob/android/src/main/java/com/sbugert/rnadmob/RNAdMobInterstitialAdModule.java:20: error: cannot find symbol.
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
                                 ^
  symbol:   class InterstitialAd
  location: package com.google.android.gms.ads
/prj/node_modules/react-native-admob/android/src/main/java/com/sbugert/rnadmob/RNAdMobInterstitialAdModule.java:36: error: cannot find symbol.
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    ^
  symbol:   class InterstitialAd
  location: class RNAdMobInterstitialAdModule
```

The development environment is as follows.

- react：16.9.0
- react-native：0.61.5
- Gradle:3.5.4
- Android 10 emulator
- react-native-admob:2.0.0-beta.6
- Android Studio:4.1.1

I have tried the following.

- Add the following to app / build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0"
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0"
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:17.0.0"
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0"
    }
}
```

- Change From com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0 to com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0
- Change from react-native-admob@2.0.0-beta.6 to react-native-admob@1.3.2
- gradlew cache clean
- node_modules delete and npm install

Please let me know if there is a solution.

Answer (score 11):

**You can solve this issue by replacing lines in node-modules/react-native-admob/android/build.gradle**

```
replace ==> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+.'

 With ==>. implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it.

1. Create a patch file with the following command

```
npx patch-package react-native-admob --exclude
```

2.Move to the directory where build.gradle is located, create the files before and after modification, and execute the following command.

```
diff -up build.gradle build2.gradle
```

※build2.gradle is the temporary file name after the change.

3.Since the difference appears in 2, paste it into the patch file created in 1. Delete all the code of the existing patch file created in 1.

4.Execute the following command to apply the created patch file.

```
npm run patch-package && cp webrtclibs/android/* node_modules/react-native-webrtc/android/libs/
```

5.build

I would be very happy if it helps someone.